# Javadoc link tag with List parameter

Tags: java, javadoc

I was writing a javadoc link tag, with the parameter List as something like this.

```
{@link #getVersionMetadata(String, String, String, List<String>)
```

It does not feel right to me. And escaping the `<` and `>` does not seem acceptable by the IDE.

```
{@link #getVersionMetadata(String, String, String, List&lt;String&gt;)
```

What is the correct way to use List<> with javadoc @link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482309/javadoc-bug-link-cant-handle-generics

Comment: Type parameters do not change the signature of the methods and so there is no chance you are going to have more than one method with two different component types for the list argument; that would result in a compilation error. So the link will always work. If what you are worried about is the text that appears in the final documentation link you can control that with a their argument for the {@link annotation.

Comment: This question is not generics.

Comment: @ValentinRuano, I think I see what you're getting at, but type parameters are significant in the signature -- the output type of a call can be affected by type parameters that appear in the signature.  Type parameters in the signature do not affect static dispatch though -- you can't overload a method by changing only type parameters so you can't affect which method is called by adding or specializing type parameters to the static type of inputs.

Comment: @MikeSamuel the return type may change but overloaded methods should pretty much do the same albeit with different input parameters. I think that if it is important for the documentation that the link (note that this is just a link) has the full list of args (specially if more than 2) to understand it, is a sign that either you are over-overloading or the documentation around that link can be written better. I think that the main reason behind the possibility of adding the formal arguments is to de-ambiguate the link itself and not documenting per se; the user should follow the link for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the text in the link to reflect the list type parameter like so...

```
   {@link #getVersionMetadata(String, String, String, List) getVersionMetaData(String,String,String,List&lt;String&gt;)}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which works in IntelliJ and actually links to the classes. I'm unsure how it will appear in other IDEs.

```
{@link List}<{@link String}>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
{@link #getVersionMetadata(String, String, String, List)}
```

Comment: But this does not denote that mine is a List of Strings?

Comment: @SenthilKumaran does it really matter, that is just a link to the corresponding documentation

Comment: Yes, I think the explanation given in this answer shows the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541824/783510